# Post Buying Request on Alibaba via API

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

How can i send post Buying request or quotation on Alibaba to get Quotations via Ali baba API.

I tried to find in the doucumentation but no such help their available,

[image: Attached Sanpshot of What i need to achieve this]

[image]

Comment: Did you find something yet?

Comment: sadly , No it was done manually by some one.